# Cannot Instantiate Json Object org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, json, spring

I was executing a `Post` Request with following `JSON` as request body:

```
{   
    "suborderCode":"qe",
    "pincode":"111006",
    "subcategoryId":175,
    "pog":"06",
    "supc":"113"

}
```

This is the corresponding handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getBreaches",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody BreachDetectionResponse getBreachesForSuborderSegments(@RequestBody SuborderData soData) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(soData.getPincode()+"asd");
        return vbdsService.getBreachesForSuborder(soData);
}
```

And this is my Pojo Class:

```
public class SuborderData {

    private Integer subcategoryId;

    private String pincode;

    private String pog;

    private String suborderCode;
    private String supc;


    public SuborderData(String pincode,Integer subcategoryId){
        this.pincode=pincode;
        this.subcategoryId=subcategoryId;

    }

    public SuborderData(String suborderCode, String pincode, Integer subcategoryId, String pog, String supc)
    {
        this.suborderCode = suborderCode;
        this.pincode=pincode;
        this.subcategoryId=subcategoryId;
        this.pog=pog;
        this.supc=supc;
    }

    public Integer getSubcategoryId() {
        return subcategoryId;
    }
    public void setSubcategoryId(Integer subcategoryId) {

        this.subcategoryId = subcategoryId;
    }
    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }
    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getSupc() {
        return supc;
    }
    public void setSupc(String supc) {
        this.supc = supc;
    }

    public String getPog() {
        return pog;
    }
    public void setPog(String pog) {
        this.pog = pog;
    }
    public String getSuborderCode() {
        return suborderCode;
    }
    public void setSuborderCode(String suborderCode) {
        this.suborderCode = suborderCode;
    }
}
```

And I am getting the following Error

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.xyz.pp.domain.SuborderData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5eadfc68; line: 2, column: 5]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.xyz.pp.domain.SuborderData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5eadfc68; line: 2, column: 5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:224)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.xyz.pp.domain.SuborderData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5eadfc68; line: 2, column: 5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1080)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3562)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2662)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:221)
    ... 39 more
```

My header is `Content/Type:Apllication-json`. The Main Problem is it is not being able to convert Json to Object

Answer (score 3):

```
 No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.xyz.pp.domain.SuborderData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Add a default constructor

```
public SuborderData() {
}
```

Jackson creates the naked object and after that it fills the fields

Answer (score 1):

You should add a default empty constructor to `SuborderData`. Another option is to annotate one of your constructors with `@JsonCreator` annotation, this way Jackson will recognize which constructor it needs to call in order to create object correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stack trace:

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.xyz.pp.domain.SuborderData]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

You need a default constructor, such as:

```
public SuborderData(){}
```